# Installing PHP on FreeBSD 10 gives compilation error

Tags: php, gnu-make, freebsd

I installed apache 2.4 on my system with

```
./configure --enable-so
```

Then MySQL got set up and running with no problem. But now I'm trying to install PHP with these parameters:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql
```

And on *make* I receive the error:

```
ext/standard/info.o: In function `php_info_print':
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
ext/standard/info.o: In function `php_info_printf':
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:83: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
ext/standard/info.o:/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: more undefined references to `ts_resource_ex' follow
ext/standard/info.o: In function `php_print_info':
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:869: undefined reference to `executor_globals_id'
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:872: undefined reference to `executor_globals_id'
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:875: undefined reference to `executor_globals_id'
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:878: undefined reference to `executor_globals_id'
ext/standard/info.o: In function `php_info_print':
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
ext/standard/info.o:/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: more undefined references to `ts_resource_ex' follow
ext/standard/info.o: In function `php_print_gpcse_array':
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:204: undefined reference to `executor_globals_id'
ext/standard/info.o: In function `php_info_print':
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
ext/standard/info.o: In function `php_info_print_html_esc':
/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:69: undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'
ext/standard/info.o:/root/php-5.5.13/ext/standard/info.c:97: more undefined references to `ts_resource_ex' follow
cc: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /root/php-5.5.13
```

Point me in the right direction plz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeBSD has the [ports collection](http://www.freebsd.org/ports/). This is a build infrastructure for all kinds of software packages. It is best to use that if what you a seeking for is available from ports. Because others have already figured out how best to install a program.

E.g. to install php5, switch to the `root` user, go to `/usr/ports/lang/php5` and give the command `make install clean`. This will compile and install PHP for you, including anything it depends on.

A lot of ports come with options; configuration items that you can change. If you are fine with the default configuration of a port, you can install it as a pre-built package. E.g. look for a PHP 5 package;

```
> pkg search php5|less
ja-php5-mecab-0.5.0
mod_php5-5.4.29,1
mod_php55-5.5.13
php5-5.4.29
php5-Ice-3.5.1
php5-arcanist-20140508_2
php5-bcmath-5.4.29
php5-blitz-0.8.2
php5-blitz-devel-0.7.2
php5-bsdconv-11.1.0
...
```

Then install the one you want;

```
# pkg install php5-5.4.29
Updating repository catalogue
The following 1 packages will be installed:

    Installing php5: 5.4.29

The installation will require 15 MB more space

2 MB to be downloaded

Proceed with installing packages [y/N]: y
```

**Edit**: To get `libphp5.so`, you need to activate the EMBED option. This is not in the defaults, so you can't use a package in that case.

Comment: If I install from ports, file libphp5.so is not created

Comment: @Nordenheim Check the port's `pkg-plist`; you have to enable the EMBED option to get `libphp5.so`.